# An error occurred while importing SQL [SQL Dump on Sequel Pro]

Tags: mysql, sql, sequelpro

I'm getting an error while trying to import the SQL dump to sequel pro.

I exported the dump from the production database.

Here's the error I get is a dialog box

```
An error occurred while importing SQL

[ERROR in query 39572] Unknown system variable 'query_cache_size'
```

Please, how do I resolve this issue?

Comment: What version of MySQL are you trying to restore the backup too? Because `query_cache_size` was removed in 8.0.3 I think

Comment: I am trying to restore to version 5.6. So, I'm currently trying to downgrade the version of MySQL on my local machine

Answer (score 2):

I simply just downgraded the MySQL version to 5.7.27 on my Mac Mojave and then tried importing the SQL dump and this error was cleared.